# Or-tools Return to Depot after Delivery

Tags: or-tools

I don't know how to modelize this kind of routes constraints in Or-Tools.

There are 2 kinds of routes (go routes, and return routes):

1. A go route can has many pickups but must have just one delivery. So the route is (Depot, Pickup, Pickup..., Delivery, Depot)
2. A return route has one pickup and many deliveries. So the route is (Depot, Pickup, Delivery, Delivery...., Depot).

Any suggestions will help a lot

Comment: do you know which vehicle has a "pickup" route and which one has a "delivery" route ?

Comment: Only a vehicle type are concerned by this rule. But inside the vehicle type it can be any of the vehicle

Comment: Which variables have you defined in you problem?